# Insert into a different table for each result of a select query

Tags: mysql, sql

If I have a setup such as:

```
set @idToIgnore = (select user_id from user_field_value where user_field_id = 82 and value = 'No';
```

Then I run a select query:

```
select id from users where account_id = 10 and id != @idToIgnore;
```

Which returns ~15 different ID values.

I then want to run a query such as:

```
insert into user_field_value(user_id, user_field_id, value) values (**user_id**, 82, 'Yes');
```

where **user_id** in the final insert query is each of the id's from the second query.

I assume there is an easy way to do this but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not just do that in one [`INSERT INTO ... SELECT ...`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-select.html) query?

```
INSERT INTO user_field_value(user_id, user_field_id, value) 
SELECT id, 82, 'Yes' FROM users 
WHERE account_id = 10 and id != @idToIgnore;
```

You can also do the whole thing in one query using subquery instead of `@idToIgnore`, but be careful in the matter of performance.